# how to create dynamic crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, report

We are able to display data in grid view dynamically.
We let the user select one of table out of 153 tables , on selection of
of any table we are able to generate a check box list containing fields of the selected table and allow user to select field/s of his choice.On pressing show data button we are able to show the corresponding data in grid view.Now my question is how can i am able to display this data in crystal report using asp.net c# .

Comment: possible duplicate of [display crystal report in asp.net page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471630/display-crystal-report-in-asp-net-page)

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading a dataset with the data you can set the crystal report datasource to the dataset.

```
cvwMain.ReportSource = New CustomersBasic()
```

Example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301570.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For generating Dynamic Crystal report follow following link

http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-dynamic-crystal-reports.htm

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-Crystal-Report-with-dynamic-columns-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx